ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)" in PyTorch
While coding Lenet5 with pytorch, Value error occurs.
This is code for dataset.
import torch
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import transforms


def get_dataset(dataset_name, batch_size=32):
  transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
  ])

  if (dataset_name == 'cifar10'):
    train_set = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    val_set = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    num_classes = 10
  elif (dataset_name == 'cifar100'):
    train_set = datasets.CIFAR100(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    val_set = datasets.CIFAR100(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    num_classes = 100
  

  train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
  val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

  return train_loader, val_loader, num_classes


And this is main code
def main():
    
    args = easydict.EasyDict({
        'epochs': 10,
        'lr': 0.001,
        'batch_size': 32,
        'dataset_name': 'cifar10'
    })      

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
    train_loader, val_loader, num_classes = get_dataset(args.dataset_name, args.batch_size)
   
    model = LeNet5BN(num_classes).to(device)
    
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)

    
    train(model, criterion, optimizer, args.epochs, train_loader, val_loader, device)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The Error occurs like this.

---> 28     train_loader, val_loader, num_classes = get_dataset(args.dataset_name, args.batch_size)
29
30
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Where did I do wrong?
I ran this code in colab, jupyter but nothing changed.
